# Redirecting from an old site to a new site

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, http-redirect

I have a very peculiar problem. Formerly, I was using Wordpress and I have a link that has a path of http://www.acetraining.com.sg/index.php/contact-us/.

I have just reverted the website to a non-Wordpress and have a static link of http://www.acetraining.com.sg/contact_us.html. How is it possible for me to redirect the old path to this new path? I already have a redirector script and I know I have to place this code :

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />`

to the head region of a html page. What I have done is that I've created an index.php as a folder name and another contact-us as a subfolder and then I created an index.html file within that but it does not work at all.

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: It's possible to use find and replace in the wordpress database and change all the old URLs to the new URLs.  Here is a link to a great tool that will do that for you.  Find the old url, replace it with the new url. 

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0):

Good morning!

I think that using meta tag for redirection will not good for your SEO. As it is a definite URL moving, I suggest you the header 301 (Redirect Permanent). You can use this by creating a .htaccess file in public_html (or your website public root directory) and put on something like this :

```
RedirectPermanent /index.php/contact-us/ http://www.acetraining.com.sg/contact_us.html
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

I have copied and pasted the code and created a .htaccess and uploaded to my root folder. However it is still not redirecting. Any reasons why? Does the .htaccess file include any other codes apart from the one you have written down?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a .htaccess file in your server root!

Create an empty text file using a text editor such as notepad, and save it as htaccess.txt and add the code blow.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect index.php/contact-us http://www.acetraining.com.sg/contact_us.html
```

NOTE:
The reason you should save the file as htaccess.txt is because many operating systems and FTP applications are unable to read or view .htaccess files by default. Once uploaded to the server you can rename the file to .htaccess

hopefully it will fix the redirection for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping! However, it is still not fixing it. I have already uploaded the .htaccess file with the codes created to my public_html. Strange thing it's not redirecting. Any reasons why this is so?

Comment: Can you add these two lines on the top of htaccess...i have updated the above answer Please copy that.


**Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On**

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have tried what you had shown me, copied + pasted the code to the .htaccess file and uploaded to the server root. I made sure I name it correctly as .htaccess also! However, it still give me the "404 - File or directory not found.". Strange. For the top part of the .htaccess, must I insert in like :
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On ---`? As this is the code that I have in the previous installation of using Wordpress? Or since I am not using Wordpress, I don't need the above lines anymore? Thanks for reading!

Comment: you don't need the above line. Can you check with your server support guys. Make sure they have permitted you to overwrite the htaccess file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already discussed with my server guys and they say I can overwrite my .htaccess file. What I cannot wrap my head around is the link "http://www.acetraining.com.sg/index.php/contact-us/." From a structure point of view, it is saying there is a contact-us folder within a index.php file. I know of files in a folder but not a folder in files! Is it common in Wordpress structure? Thanks!